# 2 issues with my WordPress blog

Tags: css, wordpress, post

http://www.florence.inspiremeland.gridhosted.co.uk/

1. I tried every single possible way to remove my feature images from my single posts while keeping the images when you visit my home page.

First of all I tried to use the following code:

```
.single-post .attachment-post-thumbnail {
  display: none;
}
```

Along with many other in my style.css or single post file without any success.

This is in my single.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="content">

            <div id="main" <?php if(get_theme_mod('sp_post_layout') == 'full') : ?>class="fullwidth"<?php endif; ?>>

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
<?php if(get_theme_mod('sp_post_layout') == 'full') : else : ?><?php get_sidebar(); ?><?php endif; ?>           
            </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Let me know what part you need from my CSS perhaps if you could help?
I am really desperate to solve this :(

2.

When I visit my blog posts the sidebar is below content and not at the side, my website is not live yet so I cannot show you that but if you could help I would really appreciate it.

Betty

Comment: Any chance of getting a link to your site so we can diagnose the problem?

Comment: 1. we need the content of `content.php`; 2. it's not possible to solve it without seeing the html source and css code

Comment: Are you able to let me know your IP address so I can allow you to see the site by adding this to my .htaccess allow list?

Comment: I have enabled the website preview mode, so you should be able to see the site here: florence.inspiremeland.gridhosted.co.uk

Comment: Ok, I found the way to remove the feature image from the content.php, now I just need to fix the problem with the side bar widgets, they seems to appear below content (if you click on blog post)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at standard.php in includes/post-formats/ and you should find something like `<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); }?>` which you can remove.

Comment: Hey, I am unable to locate that file, do I look for it under wp-includes ? (I cannot find the files there) neither under Appearance >> Editor ? sorry

Comment: Ok, I temporarily enabled the website preview mode, so you should be able to see the site here: http://www.florence.inspiremeland.gridhosted.co.uk/

Comment: To edit the theme files, look in `/wp-content/themes/florence/` – only ever touch things under `/wp-content/`, never edit `/wp-includes/` or `/wp-admin/` (what's known as "WordPress core".)

Comment: great, I managed to remove the feature images from posts, do you know any solution for the 2d problem regarding side bar widgets?